# Adaptive data-height with Bootstrap Toggle plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap Toggle plugin and I would like to have the Toggles be different sizes for different screen resolutions.

The height of a Toggle is set using a data-height attribute.  Is there a way to change the data-height via CSS?

```
<input id="btn-toggle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-width="100%" data-height="75" data-on="On Label" data-off="Off Label" data-style="stylename">

<style>
    .stylename .toggle-group {
        transition: left 0.1s;
        -webkit-transition: left 0.1s;
    }
</style>
```

Adding a height attribute to `.stylename` or `.stylename .toggle-group` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

HardlyNoticeable,  Try adding this to your css. I used the same class `.stylename`, in your ìnput`remove the 75 from the`data-height` and try resizing the window.

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
.stylename {
    height:25px;
}      
}  

@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:992px) {
.stylename{
    height:45px;
}      
}     
@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1200px) {
.stylename{
    height:55px;
}      
}    
@media(min-width:1200px) {
.stylename{
    height:75px;
}  
}
```

**Added to this post.**

[Here is a full size **Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c21qebLw/1/embedded/result/) with the code doing what you want ... resizing the Height for different screen sizes.

Grab the edge and resize the window to see that the toggles change height size.

Comment: No; sorry.  That didn't do it.  I tried assigning your styles both via the `data-style` attribute and via the `class` attribute (after removing the `data-height` attribute); but nothing doing.

Comment: Actually; if I add `!important`; it works when I use `data-style` but I still have to manually center the label top-to-bottom.
 
   `.stylename{ height:100px !important; } .stylename label { padding-top: 30px; }`

Comment: Hi there, I have added a working sample. Have a look at the Fiddle and resize it. I have only focused on the height here.

Comment: huh.  You didn't have to put `!important`.  I guess I must have something specific to my project that's making me require it.  padding-top still has to be added to the label to center it from top-to-bottom though.

Comment: Hi, For it to work it also needs to have this as well `data-height=" "`. Wont work without it, which I thought was odd too. Any way that should get you going for a way to have control of it with different screen sizes now.

Comment: I can't seem to get the label to center from top-to-bottom.  I added label styles; but they don't seem to resize properly.  See https://jsfiddle.net/tfknx3hx/

Comment: You  mean the label text? Looked to be good in your fiddle when I resize it.

Comment: Really?  It broke for me in both FF and Chrome.  Try making it wide; and press Run; and then try making it narrow and press Run again.... I wonder if it has something to do the the label height.

Comment: Remember you will need to override the toggle css. When you change padding in sm size it works. So you're on the right track by the looks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to set the Toggle height via CSS; but it seems that one must also center the Toggle Label top-to-bottom.

```
div .toggle {
    height: 100px !important;
}

div .toggle label {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Edit: The padding-top attribute seems to be ignored on resize (it only initially has the correct padding)